# Бесплатное API пробок

Tags: android, api, openstreetmap, free

Подскажите пожалуйста бесплатное API для отображения пробок на карте, если таковые ещё есть.
Хочу использовать в закрытом коммерческом мобильном приложении под Android.
Понимаю, что хочу многого, ну а вдруг :) Хотя, самому найти не удалось.

Comment: Казалось бы какие проблемы купить доступ к апи того же яндекса если приложение закрытое и коммерческое…

Comment: Это не является необходимостью, но было бы приятной плюшкой...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете попытатся использовать API от Яндекса, но у него очень душные правила с их бесплатным API. Или же 2gis https://dev.2gis.ru/

Но в основном большая часть платная

Comment: 2gis для коммерческого использования  тоже платное API насколько я понимаю. Яндекс напрямую запрещает использовать для мониторинга транспорта. Не хотелось бы нарушать правила пользования API.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/services/azure-maps/#azuremaps-overview 
Попробуй Azure от microsoft, я советовался с друзьями они вроде использовали этот

Comment: Спасибо, действительно интересный API

Comment: Обращайтесь <_>